# Does suspended @transactional method block resource?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

AFAIK `outer` method and `inner` method are run in 2 different transactions on db level (because of REQUIRES_NEW). `outer` method makes update and waits for the `inner` method to commit. Does it mean that `outer` hold lock on user resource till `inner` commits?

```
@Autowired
private TestDAO testDAO;

@Autowired
private SomeBean someBean;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outerMethod(User user) {
  testDAO.updateUser(user);
  
  someBean.innerMethod();
  
}
```

SomeBean:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void innerMethod() {
  //some work
}
```

Update:

Can this be presented like open 2 db consoles, then type and run one by one:

```
1. begin # 1st console
 
2. update user set...# 1st console
 
3. 4. 5. begin ...#do some work; commit; # 2nd console

6. commit; # 1st console
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction itself isn’t in charge of locking a row or table. If the sql executed by the dao is locking the row being updated, then that lock will be held until the transaction completes or times out. The update could be using [optimistic locking](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overview-optimistic-locking) in which case there isn’t a lock being held. So just looking at this code isn’t enough to tell if something is getting locked.

But yes, any database level locking the code does while it’s in a transaction lasts until the transaction finishes.

Comment: thank you, yes, but the question is more about a confusing transaction "suspension". Does it mean, that 6 waits for 3,4,5 to complete (see the update).

Comment: @Ekaterina: yes, the outer transaction doesn’t finish until after 5, so while it is suspended it holds whatever locks it acquired.